# Using two kit cans should I use both yeast packets and how much sugar

Tags: beer, yeast, sugar, kits

I have seen some people online using two kits to make one 23L batch of beer with more flavor than a single kit.

If you use one kit to make 23L you add the yeast supplied with it and 1kg of dextrose sugar.

Would you add both packets of yeast for adding two kits to make 23L? Also how much sugar would you add?

The kits I am talking about are coopers kits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't need to add much more sugar if you are adding twice as much extract.  Adding more sugar will depend upon what you are looking to do.  I would recommend seeing what the OG is going to be with an online tool (personally, I like [Brewer's Friend](http://brewersfriend.com)).  It would all depend upon what you are aiming for.  Adding a lot of sugar could impart a very strong alcohol taste to the beer which you may not want.

This would all depend on the style that you are creating.  Since you are adding more malt you could cut back on the dextrose (maybe 0.5 kg) due to the added sugars from the other malt kit.

You would be able to get by with only one yeast packet but using both would give you more yeast and get the fermentation going quicker.  This is assuming that the yeast is the same strain.  If they are different, it could make things interesting and that would depend on what you are aiming to make with the batch.

Check out this question for mixing yeast strains. [Using Multiple Strains of Yeast in the Same Batch?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1647/using-multiple-strains-of-yeast-in-the-same-batch)

Comment: From the OP, it seems like he just wants to make a single batch of 23L, not double the batch size.

Comment: @DennyConn yeah, I misread it.  Updated my answer.  Thanks

Comment: By doubling the extract as well as the sugar, the % of sugar will remain constant.  That shouldn't produce any more negative effect than using 1/2 as much sugar and extract.

Comment: There really isn't any negative effect at all.  Just depends on what you are aiming for.  But doubling the sugar and extract in the same size batch will increase the OG considerably.  Which I thought would be more important than the % sugar to malt.  Unless I am missing something.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that adding sugar is a problem.  It's generally acknowledged, though, that a high % of sugar (say, above 30%) can have negative flavor effects.  Since everything is increasing proportionally on this scenario, there's no worry about the % of sugar getting out of hand.